# Is there any hook for isc-dhcp-server returning the DHCPACK to client?

Tags: debian, dhcp, hook

I would like to run a script in the server after the isc-dhcp-server send the DHCPACK packet to client.

Only now I get it solution is that running a script to retrieve the dhcp log, but it is not efficient.

Any other ways? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please tell us your distro

Comment: debian7.8 isc-dhcpd-4.2.2, thks

Comment: thks, I find that in https://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/dhcp44.html#REFERENCE:%20EVENTS

Comment: using the events configure, example by:https://jpmens.net/2011/07/06/execute-a-script-when-isc-dhcp-hands-out-a-new-lease/